# Scraping: scrape multiple pages in looping (Beautifulsoup)

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape real estate data using Beautifulsoup, but when I save the result of the scrape to a .csv file, it only contains the information from the first page. I would like to scrape the number of pages I have set in the "pages_number" variable.

```
# How many pages
pages_number =int(input('How many pages? '))
# inicializa o tempo de execução
tic = time.time()

# Chromedriver

chromedriver = "./chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)


#initial link
link = 'https://www.vivareal.com.br/aluguel/sp/sao-paulo/?__vt=lnv:a&page=1'
driver.get(link)

# creating looping pages

for page in range(1,pages_number+1):
    time.sleep(15)
    data = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html' [0].innerHTML")
    soup_complete_source = BeautifulSoup(data.encode('utf-8'), "lxml")
```

I already tried this solution but got an error:

```
link = 'https://www.vivareal.com.br/aluguel/sp/sao-paulo/?__vt=lnv:a&page={}.format(page)'
```

Does anyone have any idea what can be done?

#### COMPLETE CODE

https://github.com/arturlunardi/webscraping_vivareal/blob/main/scrap_vivareal.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that the url you are using belongs to page 1 only.

```
https://www.vivareal.com.br/aluguel/sp/sao-paulo/?__vt=lnv:a&page=1
```

Are you changing it anywhere in your code? If not, then no matter what you fetch, it would fetch from page 1 only.

You should do something like this:

```
    for page in range(1,pages_number+1):
        chromedriver = "./chromedriver"
        os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

        #initial link
        link = f"https://www.vivareal.com.br/aluguel/sp/sao-paulo/?__vt=lnv:a&page={page}"
        driver.get(link)
        time.sleep(15)
        data = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html' [0].innerHTML")
        soup_complete_source = BeautifulSoup(data.encode('utf-8'), "lxml")
        driver.close()
```

Test Output (not the soup part) - for `pages_number = 3` (stored urls in a list, for easy view):

```
['https://www.vivareal.com.br/aluguel/sp/sao-paulo/?__vt=lnv:a&page=1', 'https://www.vivareal.com.br/aluguel/sp/sao-paulo/?__vt=lnv:a&page=2', 'https://www.vivareal.com.br/aluguel/sp/sao-paulo/?__vt=lnv:a&page=3']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I got an error: JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: missing ) after argument list
  (Session info: chrome=97.0.4692.71)

Comment: for page in range(1,pages_number+1):
    time.sleep(15)

    link = ("https://www.vivareal.com.br/aluguel/sp/sao-paulo/?__vt=lnv:a&page={}".format(page)). In this way I got the same error

Comment: My bad. Missed a block of code. Added that now. With this, a new browser opens for each page and once the transaction is complete, the browser closes and the loop repeats until the input number is satisfied. Now the issue here is, the `data` variable - the error is occurring here. Could you check it? The soup is not forming  properly
Also, this page may have a lot of javascript async happening. It is always better to use `wendriverwait`' instead of `time.sleep`

Comment: Please check the code in answer. I modified it, but make sure to check the soup part, for the error occurs there, not the looping the pages (with this code) - as evident from the output I pasted